# How to handle "incomplete" trial subscriptions

Tags: stripe-payments

We are currently using Stripe to offer a subscription service with 30 days free trial. Since we don't want the customer to be able to start the free trial without authorizing one payment method we use the `SetupIntent` of the created Subscription to present a card input to our client. Now the issue is that even before the customer is shown the card input the subscription is already created and "paid" for because it is a free trial.

This means that we cannot listen to the initial `invoice.paid` Webhook to activate the account, but instead need to listen to `setup_intent.succeeded`. This seems a bit odd and requires us to link the `SetupIntent` to a `Subscription`. It also means that when a customer cancels the subscription process before entering their card details, that Stripe still has created an active Subscription in trial.

Is there something we can do differently, or should we just accept that the subscriptions where the `SetupIntent` was aborted will be inactive on the Stripe side once it tries to pay for the next (non-trial) invoices?

Comment: Do you allow your customers to provide payment details at any point during the trial, or do you want to require them to provide it up front?

Comment: @karbi No. I want them to provide valid payment details before allowing them to use the trial subscription. That is why the current process is a bit awkward since the subscription immediatly exist when creating it (to use the SetupIntent to verify payment details)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe's docs use the Setup Intent that's created with a trialing Subscription to collect a customer's Payment Method, but for your use case it may make more sense to create your own Setup Intent up front and not create the Subscription unless the Setup Intent it successful. It'd go something like this:

1. Create the Setup Intent
2. Confirm the Setup Intent after collecting details
3. If successful, create the trialing Subscription

Alternatively, you could try using Checkout which does require users to submit a Payment Method even from trialing Subscriptions

Comment: Thanks. That is what i've done now. If it is a trial it returns a secret for a `SetupIntent` and only creates the Subscription in Stripe if the `SetupIntent` was successful.